# Metrofax API : How to get Fax Status Efficiently?

Tags: php, xml, api, fax, metrofax

Based on this API: https://wsf.metrofax.com/doc/

Is there any way to getStatusFromFaxId?

**The steps are:**

1. SendFaxMessage return the tracking_number
2. GetFaxMessageFrmTrkNbr to get the faxId
3. GetTransmissionStatus to get the status

For me this is not efficient (for a thousand faxes).

Is there any best, efficient way to do this? Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: That hardly seems like an outrageously inefficient process. Why don't you ask them?

Answer (score 2):

Step #3 is actually somewhat redundant in the scenario you have laid out. One can track a fax's status throughout its lifetime using only the tracking number (with no need to ever know the FaxID).

By calling GetFaxMessageFrmTrkNbr you are returned an object that contains the fax's status which should allow you to determine if the fax is still sending or has succeeded/failed. You should be able to iterate through your list of 1,000 tracking numbers (calling GetFaxMessageFrmTrkNbr for each) to check on their status, removing those that finalize from the list of items that still need to have their status checked. This is a quick call and should be fairly efficient at that kind of scale.

For any fax that ultimately fails, you may wish to optionally call GetTransmissionStatus as this will return you a human readable string for its failure reason. There is not really any need to call it for a successful fax or one that is still sending.

Comment: <ScalerResult><ResultString>Successful Send</ResultString><ResultCode>0</ResultCode></ScalerResult>

Comment: What mean in response several FaxMessage in Items by calling GetFaxMessageFrmTrkNbr?